# Do user created processes in C run parallel by linux on multi core systems?

Tags: linux, multithreading, process, fork, multicore

Do user created multiple processes in C (by fork command) run parallel on different CPUs by linux on multi core systems e.g, core i7?

I know that is the case with threads but want to be sure about the processes.

Thanks 
ALi Tariq Nagi

Comment: Why wouldn't they, especially if threads do?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The Linux kernel scheduler behaves more or less the same regardless of whether the threads it's scheduling belong to the same process or different processes.